# Как найти необходимый файл и строку в шаблоне wp, чтобы перенести блок Комментарии

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Блок Комментарии располагается в самом конце страницы(под всем содержимым), необходимо его поднять выше, как это сделать? С wp ранее дел не имел, поэтому не откажусь от развернутого ответа. Заранее спс.

Comment: А с php дело имели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартно содержимое статей в вордпрессе описывается в файле `single.php`, который располагается в папке с активной темой `\wp-content\themes\имя_темы\single.php`.

Ищите в этом файле конструкцию `<?php comments_template(); ?>` и перемещаете её в необходимое вам место